# Дублировать происходящее на мониторе компа на ноут, находящийся в той же домашней сети на Java

Tags: сеть, java, внешние-устройства

Есть задача. Дублировать всё, что происходит на экране одного из мониторов компа на экран ноута, который находится с компом в одной домашней сети. соединён по wi-fi через маршрутизатор. Собственно вот в чем вопрос: куда копать? Сделать это нужно в идеале на одном java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Уфф! Кто такие задачки придумывает?

Я бы копнул так:

1. Естественно клиент-серверное приложение
2. На стороне сервера что-то типа [Robot.createScreenCapture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture(java.awt.Rectangle)) в фоновом потоке через равные промежутки хватает скриншоты
3. Клиент берет по сетке и отображает все это у себя

Comment: добавлю, что можна быбло бы поискать спецификацию RDC протокала (все таки слать регулярно одни картинки немного накладно на траффик).  ведь есть же кроме нативного клиента клиенты под linux значит теоретически можно вкрутить и на java клиент с помощью С-шных либ

Comment: задачу сам придумал. интенсивно изучаю java, вот и решил что-то такое замутить, дабы "с головой окунуться". Спасибо за ответы

Answer (score 0):

[Почитайте](http://www.skipy.ru/philosophy/beginning.html).